# Is there a way to create an HTML button that places a phone call on click, but also redirects to a page url?

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, redirect, button

I'm trying to track conversions for my advertisements. To accomplish this I need to place code from Google onto a specific page that users would go to after "buying" or calling in my case.

My issue is that setting this code up on the homepage would be useless for tracking conversions as it would just count people coming to my home page as a sale. Is there any way the button on the home page that places a call for the user can ALSO redirect them to a 'thank you' page where I can place the conversion tracking code?

If not, is there a way to automatically place a call when the user loads a specific page?

Regards,

Chris

Comment: normally done with a setTimeout to change the page location

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming you are using google analytics? If so, you can track the button click event. Here is the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/events)

```
document.getElementById('YOUR_BUTTON_ELEMENT').onclick = function(e){
  ga('send', {
    hitType: 'event',
    eventCategory: 'YOUR_CATEGORY_NAME',
    eventAction: 'YOUR_ACTION_NAME',
    eventLabel: 'YOUR_LABEL_NAME'
  });
}
```

You can find out how you can set up the eventCategory, eventAction, and eventLabel names by reading the documentation.

I hope that helps!